# Convert LINQ written in VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to convert the following VB.NET code into C#:

```
stacks.AddRange(
    From bin In UpstreamBinNames 
    Where bin <> BinName(BeforeTrack) 
    Select binWall = ConfigGlobals.Bins(bin).Wall 
    From aStack In binWall.Stacks Select aStack)
```

I get the first part, but the last half becomes confusing. How can i rewrite this without LINQ?

Thanks.

Comment: And people wonder why semi-colons and bracers are good things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would be something like this (pardon using C#, but you should get the idea):

```
foreach(var bin in UpstreamBinNames)
{
    if(bin != BinName(BeforeTrack)
    {
        var binWall = ConfigGlobals.Bins(bin).Wall;
        foreach(var aStack in binWall.Stacks)
        {
            stacks.Add(aStack);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought but was very unsure about it. Needed to be sure. I find the linq version doesn't compute well in brain. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
var tmpStacks = new List<Stack>();
foreach(var bin in UpstreamBinNames)
{
    if (bin != BinName(BeforeTrack))
    {
        var binWall = ConfigGlobals.Bins(bin).Wall;
        foreach (var aStack in binWall.Stacks)
            tmpStacks.Add(aStack);
    }
}
stacks.AddRange(tmpStacks);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this? Use `SelectMany` to pick all stacks.

```
stacks.AddRange(UpstreamBinNames
                    .Where(bin=> bin !=  BinName(BeforeTrack))
                    .SelectMany(s=>ConfigGlobals.Bins(bin).Wall.Stacks)
               );
```

Comment: Thanks, the SelectMany is far more readable for me than the original.